# Sheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True Prompts Password

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of protected sheets in my Excel Workbook that I want to manipulate in VBA.

They are all protected with the SAME password (10+ Characters).

Before I run code that manipulates a sheet, I always say:

```
SheetName.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

This enables my code to work on the sheet.

However, my problem is that for just one of the sheets this code makes the **Unprotect** prompt appear.

This does not happen on any other sheet.

I have no idea why this could be and any problem solving help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A method I use is putting this before my code:

```
for i = 1 to countSheet
sheets.item(i).unprotect("pass")
next i
```

and putting this just before the code ends:

```
for i = 1 to countSheet
sheets.item(i).protect("pass")
next i
```

Comment: I agree this would work - I used to apply this method before I learnt about the UserInterfaceOnly setting. However I would rather spend some time trying to resolve this problem - especially as the method works perfect for my other sheets (I am editing cells that are fully protected).

Comment: Actually there is a `Sheets` collection of Workbook object which returns a Collection and it's more efficient to use the `for each` loop on Collections.